# Check if twitter account exists

Tags: php, twitter

I need to check if the twitter name user puts to the form exists or not.

I am using TwitterOAuth by Abraham Williams to do that, but I always get just false...

Here is the code:

```
require_once 'includes/twitteroauth/autoload.php';
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

define('CONSUMER_KEY', ' ');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', '');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN', '');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET', '');

function find_users(array $users){
    $founds = array();
    $toa = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

    // Up to 100 users per request.
    $userAry = array_slice($users, 0, 100);

    // Init with "not found" for all users.
    foreach ($userAry as $user) {
        $founds[$user] = false;
    }

    // Find existing users by "screen_name".
    $userObjs= $toa->post('users/lookup', array('screen_name' => implode(',', $userAry)));

    // Set "found" for existing users.
    foreach ($userObjs as $userObj) {
        $founds[$userObj->screen_name] = true;
    }

    return $founds;
}
```

Here is my call (I put there some names I know exist and also their register names, just to be sure):

```
if ($pass AND !empty($twitter)){
    $twitter_array = array($twitter, "Jayztwocents", "Barnacules", "Barnacules Nerdgasm", "Inu-ki", "Inukii", "HiRezStew", "schisam", "twitter", "twitterapi");
    $check_twitter = find_users($twitter_array);
    var_dump($check_twitter);
    die;
    if (!$check_twitter[0]){
        $message .= "<li>This twitter account does not exist.</li>";    $pass = FALSE;  $twitter_class = "required";
    }
}
```

This is the result of my var_dump:

```
array(11) {
    ["MiChAeLoKGB"]=> bool(false)
    ["Jayztwocents"]=> bool(false)
    ["Barnacules"]=> bool(false)
    ["Barnacules Nerdgasm"]=> bool(false)
    ["Inu-ki"]=> bool(false)
    ["Inukii"]=> bool(false)
    ["HiRezStew"]=> bool(false)
    ["schisam"]=> bool(false)
    ["twitter"]=> bool(false)
    ["twitterapi"]=> bool(false)
    [""]=> bool(true) 
}
```

Why does it always return false, and why the heck is as the end emty string thats true?

Ps.: All the keys/secrets are correctly set up.

PPs.: I googled a lot and there are questions about it on this site, but they all use old API which is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Ehm, I found out that I needed to create my token again and now it works well :)

Anyway, for my needs I needed to get only single user and I needed it to work even if twitter name is written with wrong caps (MYtwiTTERnAme instead of MyTwitterName), so I changed the function a bit.

Here it is, if somebody needs something like that:

```
function find_users($user){
    $toa = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

    $userObjs= $toa->post('users/lookup', array('screen_name' => $user));

    if (isset($userObjs->errors)){
        return FALSE;
    }elseif (strtolower($userObjs[0]->screen_name) == strtolower($user)){
        return $userObjs[0]->screen_name;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

And heres how you call it and test it:

```
$check_twitter = find_users($twitter);
if ($check_twitter === FALSE){
    $message .= "<li>This twitter account does not exist.</li>";    $pass = FALSE;  $twitter_class = "required";
}else{
    $twitter = $check_twitter;
}
```

Comment: And that works? If twitter accepted your search term as the user entered it, then they might still return it lowercased or somehow “sanitized” – then your function might return false, right?

Comment: The handle can have any caps you want, but if they put wrong twitter name, so it wont find it, it will return false, othervise it will return the real name of the Twitter account with proper caps and thats one I am saving. I am sanityzing it for wrong HTML/PHP characters, so if you have those in your twitter name, then GL, but you can "unsanitize" them just for the check itself.